# Why OData is missing some components with Filter criteria whereas it works fine if also provide the component Id in Query?

Tags: content-delivery, broker, odata, 2013-sp1-hr1, cache

We are facing an issue where few of our components are not appearing which we are exposing through OData.

When I hit the below query:

```
http://www-server.com/cd_webservice/odata.svc/ComponentPresentations?$filter=(TemplateId eq 111) and (PublicationId eq 22) and (ComponentId eq 555)
```

I get the expected output, whereas when I hit the below query:

```
http://www-server.com/cd_webservice/odata.svc/ComponentPresentations?$filter=(TemplateId eq 111) and (PublicationId eq 22)
```

I got results with many Components but the component "555" was missing from it which is weird.

I tried unpublishing the component (say "444") from the given results and refreshed the page & the component "444" disappeared from the results so it's clear that the query is not being cached.

On republishing the component "444", it starts appearing in the results whereas when I created the copy of the same component say "444-Copy" and published, it was missing from the OData response.

Not sure what could be the reason for this behavior, any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the problem is the number of results of the query.

By default the number of results are limited to 25, as it is configured in the `cd_webservice_conf.xml`

> ```
> <OData>
>     <DefaultTop>25</DefaultTop>
>     <FixedPublicationId>1</FixedPublicationId>
> </OData>
> ```

You can try changing this number or sorting the results to try to up your component to the first results to check this.

Including @Nuno remark about this answer, it can be added in the odata query string the meta `top`, to set the number of results, or "0" to get all the results; in the form of `&$top=xx`

Comment: You can also specify the maximum in the request itself, with something like &top=X. Use 0 to specify "no limit"

Comment: Thanks!! It will take time to change the config and test but meanwhile, I tried to modify the query but still getting the same number of results, however, I can see the count in Broker DB is 260, is my query correct? 
http://www-server.com/cd_webservice/odata.svc/ComponentPresentations?$filter=(TemplateId eq 111) and (PublicationId eq 22) and (ComponentId eq 333) & top = 0

tried also with $top = 0 ; $top=300

But No Success.

Comment: Have you tried &$top=0

Comment: Just tried now (&$top=0 without any space), and yes it worked!! thanks a lot, Nuno & Raul!!